# What's the best way to convert an Int to a String in Julia?

Tags: string, types, julia

I am using Julia (version 0.4.6), and the method that I have tried is:

```
a = 123 
println(  string(Int(a))*"b"  )
```

Which looks long and awkward.

The other way I have tried is to write it to a file, and then read it. This is clearly worse. I wonder if there is a recommended method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `*"b"` in your syntax, but for the rest of it:

```
julia> a = 123
123

julia> string(a)
"123"

julia> println(a)
123
```

The `string()` function can also take more arguments:

```
julia> string(a, "b")
"123b"
```

Note that it is not necessary to convert an `Int` type to an `ASCIIString` before calling `println()` on it - the conversion will occur automatically.

You can also insert (aka interpolate) integers (and certain other types) into strings using `$`:

```
julia> MyString = "my integer is $a"
"my integer is 123"
```

**Performance Tip:** The above methods can be quite convenient at times.  But, if you will be performing many, many such operations and you are concerned about execution speed of your code, the Julia [performance guide](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#avoid-string-interpolation-for-i-o) recommends against this, and instead in favor of the below methods:

You can supply multiple arguments to `print()` and `println()` which will operate on them exactly as `string()` operates on multiple arguments:

```
julia> println(a, "b")
123b
```

Or, when writing to file, you can similarly use, e.g.

```
open("/path/to/MyFile.txt", "w") do file
    println(file, a, "b", 13)
end
```

or

```
file = open("/path/to/MyFile.txt", "a")
println(file, a, "b", 13)
close(file)
```

These are faster because they avoid needing to first form a string from given pieces and then output it (either to the console display or a file) and instead just sequentially output the various pieces.

**Note:** Answer reflects updates based on helpful comment from @Fengyang Wang.

Comment: Great answer. Note that `string()` is as slow as string interpolation. In fact, string interpolation actually lowers down to a `string` call! The linked performance guide recommends using IO functions directly, which is indeed faster.

Comment: @FengyangWang Great, thanks for the tip!  I've updated accordingly.